# Export WIT xml from Visual Studio failed

Tags: xml, azure-devops

I was trying to export a WIT XML from Visual Studio 2017 - Professional

[image]

but I got the message as the attached snapshot

```
Error exporting work item type definition: The feature is disabled....
```

I was told that I need to be the project administrator. Yes, I've the admin permission for this project, but still didn't work for me.

Anything else that I need to config? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/115108/witadmin-exportwitd-this-feature-is-disabled.html

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I want. I defined several new WITs already through the web,  and a co-worker can export these WITs' xml to edit through VSTS directly which is much convenient.  I added him to the project as a early adopter. He can export the WIT XML. But I'm the project admin, why I could't export. So this is quiet confusing to me.

Comment: Did you export the XML for the same project and WIT with he?

Comment: @Totoro There are two models for work item customization. The one you're trying to use from Visual Studio is the **old** one, and it does not work against VSTS (except in the case where the account was migrated from an on-prem TFS instance).